# How to check if the repository is from SVN or Git?

Tags: java, git, svn, java-8

We are working on a solution which browses local repository and need to determine whether it's from SVN or Git.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the presence of the folders `.svn` and `.git`, or issue the commands `svn info` and `git info` on the repository folder in otder to get a successfully feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Check for the existance of an `.git` file/folder or `.svn` folder at the root of the checked out repository.

Alternatively, use a git/svn library and try to initialize it on a given path.